# How to connect Airflow with IA Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am in a project and I need to connect Airflow to IA Platform (Artificial Intelligence Google Cloud). Are there any connectors I can use? And I also need to start a job from there. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please so not get me wrong, but could you state how you tried to solve this problem so far?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Airflow GCP Operator?

> Airflow has extensive support for the Google Cloud Platform.
>
> [See the GCP connection](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/connection/gcp.html) type documentation to configure connections to GCP.
>
> All hooks are based on `airflow.gcp.hooks.base.GoogleCloudBaseHook`.

see: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators-and-hooks-ref.html#gcp-google-cloud-platform

Alternatively, Google has productise the Apache Airflow into Google Cloud Composer which has inbuilt integrations with Google AI services. So using Cloud Composer might prove beneficial in a long run.